Dynatrace agent POD consuming more NODE memory in AKS
I have installed Dynatrace agent classic full stack deployment by following this link
Oneagent and activegate pods are consuming more memory compared to our actual micro service in the AKS cluster. I have not found any Dynatrace documentation with explaining on memory consumption. Is there a way to reduce this memory consumption by enabling or disabling some feature of Dynatrace?
Not providing any configuration yamls here, please provide what can i configure which reduce this memory consumption.


Not providing any configuration yamls here - it's hard to help without more details, including code :-(

You can set the resource settings for OneAgents and ActiveGates in your DynaKube yaml.
Suggested values can be found in the classicFullStack.yaml example file.
But assuming the values shown are in MB, they are in a normal range of what a OneAgent will consume. There isn't really a lot you can do as memory consumption of the Agent Pod doesn't scale a lot with the number of Microservices running on the node. If you had a lot more services, it still wouldn't consume significantly more RAM.
